# Does Linux represent an opened directory in the same way as an opened file?

Tags: files, linux-kernel, directory

Linux kernel represents an opened file   as an entry in the file descriptor table, an entry in the v-node table, and an entry in the open file table.

Does Linux kernel represent an opened directory   in the same way?

It might be not, because I was wondering why   an directory is opened by:

```
DIR *opendir(const char *pathname);
```

while a file is opened by:

```
int open(const char *path, int oﬂag, ... /* mode_t mode */ );
```

It might be yes, because

```
DIR *fdopendir(int fd);
```

converts an open ﬁle descriptor into a DIR structure. So is there some function (`open()`?) which can open a directory just like a file, and return a file descriptor `fd`?

Is `opendir()` implemented by first using `open()` to get a file descriptor of a directory, and then calling `fdopendir()` or some equivalence on the file descriptor?

Thanks.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克, `O_PATH` doesn't seem to have anything to with reading the listing of a directory, though: "Obtain a file descriptor that can be used [...] to indicate a location in the filesystem tree." -- "The file itself is not opened, and other file operations fail"

Comment: Does linux really have a "v-node table"? Where?

Comment: @ilkkachu You're right, I misread open ()

Comment: @mosvy  Is it an inode table instead? I think you  got the idea?

Answer (score 4):

`opendir` is a library function that calls the `open` system call internally, just like `fopen` is a library function that internally calls `open`. `opendir` returns a pointer to a directory stream `DIR`, analogously to `fopen`, which returns a pointer to a file stream `FILE`. You can also use the `open` system call directly on a directory, if you so wish.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there some function (`open()`?) which can open a directory just like a file, and return a file descriptor fd?

Yes, you can open a directory with [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and get a file descriptor to it. You'll need the file descriptor if you use `openat()`.

On Linux, you can't `read()` from a directory, though, it'll return `EISDIR`, ("Is a directory"). Instead the kernel has the [`getdents()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html) system call to read directory entries from an opened directory. Confusingly, there's also the obsolete [`readdir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readdir.2.html) system call (though not on newer architectures), which is different from the POSIX function with the same name.

As the man page for `getdents()` says, glibc doesn't provide wrappers for it, so you should probably use the [POSIX `readdir()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) and `opendir()` functions instead. So yes, `opendir()` uses `open()` internally, the C library just does what it needs on top to provide the standard API with `DIR *`.

As far as I understand, some other Unix-likes allow using `read()` on directories too, instead (or in addition to?) having a distinct system call for getting a listing of files.

Linux's [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) also has the `O_DIRECTORY` flag which causes the open to fail if the named file isn't a directory, but using that is not mandatory.

Comment: Linux does **not** have a `readdir()` system call. I know that there's such a compatibility syscall on i386 (which is using a different `struct dirent`), but for all intents and purposes, **that syscall does not exist** ;-) -- namely, there's no such syscall on x86-64, arm/eabi and arm64.

Comment: @mosvy, right, the man page does say at the bottom "This system call does not exist on x86-64."